# Equivalente de eval() en C#

Tags: c#, python

soy nuevo en C# y queria saber si existe alguna funcion equivalente a eval() de python pero en C#.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Debido a la naturaleza "compilada" del lenguaje C# a diferencia de python que es "interpretado", un evaluador de codigo en tiempo de ejecucion no es soportado por el lenguaje. Pero existen otras opciones para casos puntuales (evaluar expresiones con variables, por ejemplo). Especifica que tipo de evaluacion esperas realizar.

Comment: En Python usaba eval de esta manera:

Comment: operacion = "2+2"

Comment: eval(operacion) y me devolvía 4

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Se podría saber porque? Es decir, mi pregunta se entendió y obtuve una buena respuesta que me funcionó por cierto.

Answer (score 2):

No existe como tal una funcion equivalente, pero puedes hacer algo similar con el metodo *DataTable.Compute()* de la clase *DataTable*:

```cs
static int Eval(String expression)
{
    var table = new System.Data.DataTable();
    return Convert.ToInt32(table.Compute(expression, String.Empty));
}
```

Y lo usas tal que:

```cs
var res = Eval("2 + 4"); //resultado es 6
```

Comment: Lo intentaré; gracias!